# Revert to upstart

Tags: init, systemd, sysv

Is it possible to revert an ubuntu 14.10 install to a upstart or a SysV init system. 
The "loggin" and other issues with systemd has caused me issus with being unable to read the dmesg as normal and determine if my stability issues are from systemD or something else.

Comment: How did you install `systemd`? Also post the output of `which init`.

Comment: It was installed when I installed the system,
Which init points to /sbin/init.
Dmesg is corupted by all the "systemd" messages.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to follow that https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers guide. You can either

- use upstart for a single boot by following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Switch_to_upstart_for_a_single_boot
- or permanently by following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Permanent_switch_back_to_upstart

I just reverted to upstart by doing `sudo apt-get install upstart-sysv`. The systemd option is still available in the grub menu under "Advanced options > Ubuntu, with Linux ... (systemd)"