# how to use the upstart command instead of systemctl

Tags: upstart, services, gdm

I am a newcomer to Linux and Ubuntu; I was about to start the gdm environment with the command `sudo start gdm` but I got this message error:

```
 start: unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket
 /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Searching more about this issue I realised that I have to move from `upstart` to `systemd` and Upstart is no longer used by Ubuntu.

But when I type `which upstart` I get `/sbin/upstart`; while `which systemctl` gave `/bin/systemctl`.

My question is, how can I use upstart, since it is installed already on my system?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. **Upstart** is installed on Ubuntu 16.04 because some small parts of it are used for specific tasks. Ubuntu uses **systemd** as the init system, including control of services. Syntactically, you command should be `sudo systemctl start gdm`; whether if would make sense or not is a different question.

Comment: [Strictly speaking, xe can](http://askubuntu.com/questions/582200/); but doing so is possibly not the best idea for a novice.

Comment: @JdeBP: Well, you are right, they _can_, for suitably chosen values of _can_.